# attributeerror: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

Actually I want to make a Many2many field dynamic

```
allowed_economic_activity_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'izi.economic.activity', string='Allowed Economic Activities' domain=_filtrar_actividades)

@api.onchange('allowed_economic_activity_ids','invoice_line_ids')
def _filtrar_actividades(self):
    if self:
        query = self.env['izi.economic.activity'].search([('id','!=','1')])
        if query:
            domain = [('id', 'in', query.ids  )]
        return domain
```

When add @api.onchage it doesn't works and display an error "attributeerror: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'"
The value of the many2many field should change when clinck on allowed_economic_activity_ids field or invoice_line_ids

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following in [_onchange_eval](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/models.py#L6189) docstring:

> while domain and warning messages are put in dictionary `result`

Odoo expects the onchange function to return a dictionary and not a list.

You can define a computed field and then use it in a field domain as they did in the OCA [base_tier_validation](https://github.com/OCA/server-ux/blob/16.0/base_tier_validation/models/tier_definition.py#L48)

```
reviewer_field_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name="ir.model.fields",
    string="Reviewer field",
    domain="[('id', 'in', valid_reviewer_field_ids)]",
)

valid_reviewer_field_ids = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name="ir.model.fields",
    compute="_compute_domain_reviewer_field",
)

@api.depends("review_type", "model_id")
def _compute_domain_reviewer_field(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.valid_reviewer_field_ids = self.env["ir.model.fields"].search(
            [("model", "=", rec.model), ("relation", "=", "res.users")]
        )
```